# Why are the instructions ENTER and LEAVE not used by compilers?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, compiler-optimization

Reading a program's disassembly, I've noticed a pattern. When setting up a function's frame, the instruction `enter` is rarely used. I also used compiler explorer with the latest GCC -- GCC does not use `enter` but uses `leave`.

Why isn't the instuction `enter` used? Why do compilers use two or more instructions to preform an action that can be done in one instruction? (pushing rbp, saving rsp, and allocating on the stack using `sub rsp`, rather than using `enter 0x20, 0`). But `leave` is used... is there something else that `leave` does that I'm not aware of? As far as I know, `leave` is equivalent to

```
mov ebp, esp
pop ebp
```

GCC uses `leave` whereas MSVC does not. I don't understand why `enter` is never used and `leave` is sometimes used.

Comment: tl;dr: One instruction instead of two doesn't always mean faster.

Comment: Yeah that's good, thanks.

Comment: The problem is not what `leave` does, it's what `enter` does. `enter` is *insane*, it was supposed to give assembly support for nested stack frames in block structured high-level languages. Because the general form of `enter` *cannot* be made fast by a modern processor, even the *less insane* version that only reserves stack space for the current stack frame has been neglected by processor implementers. If you look at Agner Fog's instruction tables, you see `enter a, 0`  ~3-4x slower than `push; mov; sub`, and `enter a,b` effectively taking an eternity.

Comment: Also, modern compilers can usually avoid using frame pointers (because modern debug and unwind tables make frame pointers redundant), so frame pointers are mostly a relic of the past, particularly on register starved architectures like x86(_64), where an extra register for the compiler's register allocator is *very* valuable.

Comment: Oh? I still have two questions. If we don't use `enter`, why is `leave` sometimes used? Also, where can I learn more about unwind tables? (Like examples) @EOF

Comment: `leave` is *much simpler*, it really is only `mov; pop`. Compilers use `leave` under the following conditions: 1) The function uses variable-legth arrays, `alloca()`, the target ABI *requires* a frame pointer or the programmer explicitly requests that the compiler produce worse code by using a frame pointer AND 2) The code density advantage (a single instruction with a single-byte opcode versus multiple instructions, one of which takes multiple bytes to encode) outweighs the execution speed disadvantage (which is pretty small).

Comment: If you want to learn about debug info and unwind tables, you need to ask somebody else, because I have no idea how they actually work. You might find something useful by searching for `dwarf debug info`.

Comment: Thanks man, especially for that explanation on `leave` @EOF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are the instructions ENTER and LEAVE not used by compilers?

These instructions have been used in the [i286](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80286) and [i386](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80386) era, so before 1999.

Today, these machine instructions are *generally*
slower than simpler equivalents. Compiler writers do know that, so avoid emitting these machine instructions.

Comment: It was already available in i186. Really old!